# Is it possible to join table as below in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

how can I join two tables with multiple columns in laravel, somthing like the below query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tab1 AS e
INNER JOIN
    tab2 AS v ON v.Case1 = e.Case1 and v.id = e.id;
```

I have searched in google but could not find any way.

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
DB::table('tab1 as e')
    ->join('tab2 as v', 'v.Case1', '=', 'e.Case1', 'and', 'v.id', '=', 'e.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: anything is possible..
What have you tried so far?
you can use the above query using `Db::select('SELECT *
FROM tab1 as e
INNER JOIN tab2 as v
ON v . Case1 = e . Case1 and v . id = e . id;');`

Comment: I used query builder join function but it gives error

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins: "Advanced Join Clauses"

Comment: Can you show the code you tried that gave you an error?

Comment: @RossWilson   this is the code I Tried.           
            
            'DB::table('tab1 as e')
            ->join('tab2 as v', 'v.Case1', '=', 'e.Case1', 'and', 'v.id', '=', 'e.id')->get();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
DB::table('tab1 as e')
->join('tab2 as v', function($join)
{
   $join->on('v.Case1', '=', 'e.Case1');
   $join->on('v.id','=', 'e.id');

})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you have to go around it and it must work.
Take this example of mine I did and it works

```
 $categ =  DB::connection('mysql')->table('SubCategories')
                 ->leftJoin('Categories', 'Categories.id', '=', 'SubCategories.categories_id')
            ->select('SubCategories.id','SubCategories.Code','SubCategories.Name','SubCategories.Description','Categories.Name as CategoryName'
              )
            ->get();

DB::connection('your connection from app.php file')table('tab1 as e')
    ->join('tab2 as v', 'v.Case1', '=', 'e.Case1', 'and', 'v.id', '=', 'e.id')
    ->Select('your select statement'),
    ->get();
```