# How to create SQL Join Statement in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two table `customer_id` namely `tbl_customer` and `tbl_stocks` connected on the same database. My logic about this problem is JOIN sql statement.

This is for Laravel and MySQL, so far i've tried this on PHP and is working fine but when I implement it on laravel it is not working i wonder why?

here is my code in PHP and want to convert it to laravel but I dont know where to put? will i put it in the View or in the Controller

```
$query = "SELECT c.*, s.* FROM tbl_customer c JOIN tbl_stock s ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id AND c.customer_id = 1";
```

**Controller**

```
$data = DB::table('tbl_customer')
            ->join ......  //Im not sure about this 
            ->select ....  // neither this 
            ->get();

            print_r($data)
```

**Model**

*I have no codes on my model*

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/admin/shopcontrol', 'Admin\ShopsController@testquery');
```

I expect a result of fetching or getting the query or result of the values in just a simple `echo` and the fetch join is connected

Comment: have you made eloquent models and relationships?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din yes sir, would you like me to show it and edit my code ?

Comment: if you created eloquent models and their relationships, please post them in your question.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din DONE! sir please see thanks

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din i've edit my question please take a look thanks

Comment: Actually to use laravel [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent), you must create `Model` per table. in your example there are 2 tables so 2 `Model`s.

Then create [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) between those models, after that you can create a query between those tables and filter it as you want.

I'm sorry I can't explain more. just read the documentation please.

Comment: see this link it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457659/is-it-possible-to-join-table-as-below-in-laravel/53478080#53478080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Laravel site?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

It has a demonstration you could use to reorganize your code.

As it follows below from the site.

Joins
Inner Join Clause

The query builder may also be used to write join statements. To perform a basic "inner join", you may use the join method on a query builder instance. The first argument passed to the join method is the name of the table you need to join to, while the remaining arguments specify the column constraints for the join. Of course, as you can see, you can join to multiple tables in a single query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

You may find more information there if it suits you.

Comment: can you refer to my code sir @Dende ? i knew php join but im having a hard time on laravel syntax please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $data = DB::table('tbl_customer')
                ->join('tbl_stock', 'customer_id', '=', 'tbl_customer.customer_id')
                ->select('tbl_customer.*', 'tbl_stock.*')
                ->where('customer_id', '=', 1) 
                ->get();
```